# Firefox in windows 11 is not throwing online/offline events

Tags: firefox

I have a component that depends on browser events for online/offline events to let know the user when he is disconnected from the activity.

I was checking on firefox, and for some reason Im not able to see the event been emitted when disabling the network (I did test it,  turn it the wifi on/off).

in the image , there is side by side with chrome and firefox, so I know my event listener works, but doesnt seems like firefox is sending the events,

I have a js using same examples from the documentation,

has someone else notice this? , or is some sort of settings in firefox?, according to the documentation it should be supported by default,

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Online Offline</title>
    </head>



    
<script type="text/javascript">

    console.log(" ******** Online Offline in real time **********");




    const handlerOnline = async () => {
        console.log("online handler :: ", new Date().toISOString());
    };

    const handlerOffline = async () => {
        console.log("offline handler :: ", new Date().toISOString());
    };

    window.addEventListener("online", () => handlerOnline(), false);

    window.addEventListener("offline", () => handlerOffline(), false);

    window.document.addEventListener("online", () => handlerOnline(), false);

window.document.addEventListener("offline", () => handlerOffline(), false);

    window.onoffline = (event) => {
        console.log("1:: The network connection has been lost.");
    };

    window.ononline = (event) => {
        console.log("A:: online");
    };



    window.addEventListener("offline", (event) => {
        console.log("2:: The network connection has been lost.");
    });

    window.addEventListener("online", (event) => {
        console.log("B:: online");
    });

    window.addEventListener("offline", (event) => {
        console.log("3:: The network connection has been lost.");
    });


</script>



</html>
```